# How to grant the application admin rights with InnoIDE

Tags: inno-setup

I have a C# windows forms application that needs Admin rights to stored the information in registry. I'm using InnoIDE to install my application, but my problem is that i want to grant my application Admin rights on install.

I don't want the user to continuously open the application as an administrator(right click, run as administrator) every time they want to open the Application.

Any ideas ?

Comment: In general, that's just wrong! The application should not need Admin rights!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thank you, this solved my problem.

Comment: How can do i accept a duplicate ? I clicked on the up arrow.